# Issues with dockerizing react project

Tags: reactjs, docker

I am trying to dockerize a react project. When I look into the /usr/share/nginx/html the directory does not have my react project files.

react project file structure

```
-React
    -public
    -src
    -othr files
    -Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

#STEP 2 CREATE NGINX SERVER
FROM nginx:latest AS prod-stage
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

Comment: I suggest to take a look at the intermediate image "build" and check if everything is what you expect. Also, `COPY . .` will copy the node_modules/ from the host to the image *after* npm-installing in the image. This might lead to conflicts, make sure it doesn't!

Comment: Usually you can address the problem @NikosParaskevopoulos mentions by including `node_modules` in a `.dockerignore` file.  Also make sure to `COPY package-lock.json .` so you get a reproducible list of package versions.